# How to create dynamic dropdownlist using php in HTML with Parse.com Cloud DB

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, html, parse-platform

I have a database in Parse Cloud. and would like to retrieve the data in dropdown lists. I have 4 dropdowns, as I select first dropdown its related lists should be displayed into second dropdown list and further into third dropdown etc.
For Ex.: first dropdown is list of courses, as I select the course, its related subjects should be displayed into second dropdown, and after selecting subject list its concerned chapters should be displayed in the next dropdown.

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Dynamic Dependent Select Box </title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(".course").change(function()
    {
        var id=$(this).val();
        var dataString = 'id='+ id;

        $.ajax
        ({
            type: "POST",
            url: "get_chapter.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(html)
            {
                $(".year").html(html);
            } 
        });
    });


    $(".year").change(function()
    {
        var id=$(this).val();
        var dataString = 'id='+ id;

        $.ajax
        ({
            type: "POST",
            url: "get_subject.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(html)
            {
                $(".subjects").html(html);
            } 
        });
    });

});
</script>
<style>
label
{
font-weight:bold;
padding:10px;
}
div
{
    margin-top:100px;
}
select
{
    width:200px;
    height:35px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<center>
<div>
<label>Course :</label> 
<select name="course" id="course" class="course">

<option value = "">Select...</option>
<?php foreach($course_array as $category) {$category = htmlspecialchars($category);?>
<option value="<?php echo $category; ?>"><?php echo $category; ?></option>
<?php
}
?>
  </select>

<label>Year :</label> <select name="year" id="year" class="state">
<option selected="selected">--Select Year--</option>
</select>


<label>Subjects :</label> <select name="subjects" class="city">
<option selected="selected">--Select Subjects--</option>
</select>

</div>
```

Comment: in "get_chapter.php" file I have an php array of list of Year based on course selected, and in "get_subject.php" I have an php array of list of Subjects based on the course and the year selected. ..

Comment: When I select course.. its particular year is displayed correctly into dropdown. but when i select on year (I Year) its corresponding subjects are not been displayed into the subject dropdown... appreciate your help thanks

Answer (score 1):

So as per your example first load all the courses into your dropdown.
Then on change event of your first dropdown write an ajax call to get the related subjects(in your case) and then onchange of your subject write another ajax call to get the data for next dropdown and so ...

Another approach can be on change of each dropdown submit the form and receive the value in your page using $_GET or $_POST and based on your value populate your select box

Hope It will help you

Comment: Can you please provide me code snippet as I am very new to ajax and jquery.. that would help me alot.. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you can use this tricks.

https://github.com/hendcorp/dynamic-dropdown

It use jQuery *onchange* method to call another page with $_GET method.
On that github example, you just need to create 2 pages.

First, create the master page that contain master dropdown and an empty dropdown. And then, create `helper.php` to generate new value for your empty dropdown based on selected value on master dropdown.

But on that sample, the data generated with array. Just replace the array with your data source and it should be work.